# What is the reference of the Hadith about the leader and army who will conquer Constantinople?

Tags: hadith, source-identification

What is the reference of Hadith which approximately means that a blessed leader and blessed army will conquer Istanbul

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps you mean this hadith:

> #### لتفتحن القسطنطينية، ولنعم الأمير أميرها، ولنعم الجيش ذلك الجيش
>
> Verily you shall conquer Constantinople. What a wonderful leader will that leader be, and what a wonderful army will that army be!

Recorded in, for example:

- [Musnad Ahmad - مسند الكوفيين - حديث بشر بن سحيم](https://al-maktaba.org/book/13157/19316#p1)
- [Mustadrak al-Hakim -  كتاب الفتن والملاحم](https://al-maktaba.org/book/2266/9160)
- [Mu'jam al-Kabir Tabarani - باب الباء - بشر الغنوي](https://al-maktaba.org/book/1733/1462)